# What return ostream::write?

Tags: c++, file

Cplusplus say "The ostream object (* this)" but I do not understand. Return ostream object's pointer? I have try print this value with cout function but I print always 0. And how can this value be useful?

Comment: It means a reference to the stream you are writing to.

Comment: And please don't use cplusplus as a reference, or for anything else.

Comment: Give [this reference a try](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write).  Also, do you know what you get then you do `*this`?

Comment: "What return ostream::write?" - It returns `basic_ostream&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in C++, methods' classes that don't have to return a specific value, like in this case (or with `string` for example), return `*this`.

> Every object in C++ has access to its own address through an important pointer called this pointer. The this pointer is an implicit parameter to all member functions. Therefore, inside a member function, this may be used to refer to the invoking object.

Thanks to `this`, you can use the method chaining, this is an example:

```
char c[]="This this this";
std::cout << (std::cout.write(c,4) << " hello ") << std::endl;
```

Output:
`This hello 0x600e08`

In this example I used operator chaining on purpose, but it's the same with methods.

`0x600e08` is address of your `basic_ostream` object.

Answer (score 2):

```
this
```

is a pointer to the current object invoked.

```
*this
```

dereferences the pointer.

This is often used for "chaining".
For instance:

```
cout<<1<<2<<3<<4<<5;
```

operator<< is invoked in cout:
    cout<<1
will print 1 and return cout, then we'll have:

```
cout<<2<<3<<4<<5;
```

and so on.